# ¿Uso de lo y le por país?

Tags: diferencias-regionales

En un artículo de wikipedia venía esto:

> Se lo llama:

pero para mí es más común decir:

> Se le llama:

Se está hablando de cómo se **le** llama a un derivado de leche quemada en diferentes países (Dulce de leche, cajeta, arequipe etc.)

Para mí, lo más natural es usar **le** y sé que existen diferencias de uso, lo noto sobre todo con libros impresos en España, creía que eran simples diferencias regionales sin gran trasfondo más que costumbre por usar uno u otro. Edité el artículo y puse **le**, después deshicieron mi corrección y agregaron un comentario:

> No, es una cosa: "lo".

Esto me deja pensando que el uso de "le" y "lo" tiene un significado específico, ¿podrían explicarme a que se refiere con que es una cosa y en qué países existe esta diferencia?

Answer (score 4):

Según [la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=llamar)

> hoy se recomienda el uso de los pronombres *lo(s)*, *la(s)*, pues el complemento que expresa la persona o cosa nombrada funciona como sujeto en la construcción pasiva: *La niña fue llamada Juana*; a esto se añade que el complemento predicativo, que es el que expresa el nombre o calificativo aplicado, solo puede referirse gramaticalmente a un sujeto o a un complemento directo, nunca a un complemento indirecto.

En el mismo artículo también reconocen que ambas formas se usaron y se siguen usando hoy en día:

> Ya desde los orígenes el español vaciló entre usar en este caso las formas de dativo *le(s)* o las de acusativo *lo(s)*, *l(a)s*, vacilación que se ha mantenido hasta la época actual.

Con respecto a quien te dijo "es una cosa", se refiere a lo siguiente, descripto en la entrada sobre [*leísmo*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=DRC2Ny6YAD6yEoSWaX) de la RAE:

> Debido a su extensión entre hablantes cultos y escritores de prestigio, se admite el uso de *le* en lugar de *lo* en función de complemento directo cuando el referente es una 
>   persona de sexo masculino

pero:

> El leísmo no se admite de ningún modo en la norma culta cuando el referente es inanimado

De todas maneras, como se ve en el primer artículo, esta regla no se aplica en el caso de este verbo en particular:

> En España a la papa **le** llaman patata

No es una frase considerada "inculta" por la RAE, aunque se prefiera la forma con *la*.

Answer (score 1):

En efecto, el uso de *le* y *lo* induce a muchas personas a confusión. Entre ellas, la que revirtió tu cambio en la Wikipedia. En este caso, el objeto directo es lo que venga después de los dos puntos; el pronombre en discordia es el objeto indirecto y, por tanto, solo puede ser *le*, independientemente de su género o de si se refiere a persona o cosa.

Según cómo sea la frase completa, también podemos considerar que ese pronombre es redundante y eliminarlo por completo, o reescribirla para que este objeto indirecto pase a ser sujeto, con lo que puede quedar una oración más natural sin el pronombre. Por ejemplo:

> `En los distintos países, este tipo de postre se llama:`

Answer (score 0):

Tenía entendido que *lo* es acusativo y *le* es dativo. La confusión me parece que viene del uso de la preposición *a* para el objeto directo, lo cual confunde a mucha gente.

Ejemplo:

Esperamos a tu hermano. -> *Lo esperamos*.